# Replacing part of a string with a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen this question posted on here but none of the answers seem to be an actual Component or haven't worked so I am going to post my question and see if I missed anything.

I am making a blog with a body section for the use to add a story. I would like to have a special set of characters '{{21}}' in the body to indicate it should be replaced with a PhotoDeck component and pass in the photos from list 21. In my API I am able to parse the text, look for the marker, get the id, and add it to the api return as an array of objects:

```
inline_photos": [
{
"list_id": "21",
  "photos": [
    "/img/ODdiNzUwODMtZTBiZi00MTE2LTg1NjEtYTkyYjU3OWUyNzQxLmpwZw20210127010134.jpeg",
    "/img/YmFsaS5wbmc20210127010135.png"
  ]
},
{
"list_id": "22",
  "photos": [
    "/img/MDFfRXVyb3BlLmpwZw20210222030245.jpeg",
    "/img/ZGVhYWM5OWRfb3JpZ2luYWwuanBn20210222030246.jpeg"
  ]
}
]
```

In my react component that displays the page, I am importing the PhotoDeck component that takes in a prop of 'photos';

I pass the body to a function that I would like it to loop over the inline_photos array and replace the {{21}} and {{22}} in the string with component and the photos from the inline array.

I thought something like:

```
const get_inline = body => {
    if(post.inline_photos.length){
      post.inline_photos.map( list => {
          body = body.replace(`{{${list.list_id}}}`,<PhotoDeck photos={list.photos} />);
      })
    }else{
      return body;
    }
  }
```

It returns, as expected, [Object, Object] due to the component being rendered as a string when replaced. I have seen a number of regex libraries posted as a solution but the issue for me isn't finding the markers to replace, its the actual 'inserting' of a component in place of it.

```
<h2>Why Bali?</h2><p>[object Object]Twenty-two hours in-flight (from Toronto) and fifteen hours in layovers later, we found ourselves in a dream of a location, Bali. We could not have picked a better destination to spend our honeymoon in. When we were researching where to celebrate our marriage, we wanted to go somewhere special, where we could be both adventurous and lazy bums, without breaking bank.&nbsp;</p>
```

here is a small sample of the actual body text:

```
<h2>Why Bali?</h2><p>{{21}}Twenty-two hours in-flight (from Toronto) and fifteen hours in layovers later, we found ourselves in a dream of a location, Bali. We could not have picked a better destination to spend our honeymoon in. When we were researching where to celebrate our marriage, we wanted to go somewhere special, where we could be both adventurous and lazy bums, without breaking bank.&nbsp;</p>
```

Can this be done? Thanks!

//Update//
I used react-string-replace and I am not getting this in the array it produces. Is it not rendering the completed component and is there something I am not doing?

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {photos: Array(5)}
ref: null
type: ({ cards }) => {…}
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 0, key: null, stateNode: null, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, …}
_store: {validated: false}
_self: undefined
_source: {fileName: "D:\src\components\postbody\PostBody.js", lineNumber: 19, columnNumber: 12}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) - but this is really an anti-pattern. You're taking all the fun away from React - it is optimized to do the template parsing for you.

Comment: Have you tried using a template string for this task or ternary operator? Seems to be a solution.

Comment: @Randy - I was using ReactHtmlParser to render out my html in the page but are you saying that dangerouslySetInnerHTML would render the component that is being replaced in the string?

Comment: @rom - where are you suggesting I would use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for me the solution was to use react-string-replace (github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace) and pass in the marker and replace it with the component. The return was an array of text and the component object which I assigned to a 'story' state.

```
...
const [story, setStory] = useState([]);
...
    useEffect(() => {
        if(post.inline_photos.length){
          post.inline_photos.map( list => {
             post.body = reactStringReplace(post.body, `{{${list.list_id}}}`, (match, i) => (
               <div className="photo-deck-container"><div id="photo-deck"><PhotoDeck cards={list.photos} /></div></div>
              ));
          })
        }
        setStory(post.body);
        return;
      },[post])
```

(Its inside a map since the body could contain multiple markers)

Then in the story, I mapped over the value and if it was an object, I printed it to the screen else I passed it to ReactHtmlParser to render the html text.

```
  { story.map( (piece,i) => {
            return typeof(piece)==='object' ? piece : ReactHtmlParser(piece)
  })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what I meant:

```
body = list.list_id === 21 ? 
body.replace(`{{${list.list_id}}}`,<PhotoDeck photos={list.photos} />) 
: <PhotoDeck photos={list.photos} />
```

Because if you want to replace something with an entire component based on some kind of condition where it needs to be the number 21, the first place I would think would be using a ternary operator where you put a ? and :

See [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

“The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark (?), then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy followed by a colon (:), and finally the expression to execute if the condition is falsy. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement.”

Comment: I am trying to replace the markers in the body content with a components. I know the markers are in the body but I am not sure how to merge the rendered component into the body of the blog post.